# How to successfully $_POST <options> from a <select> to another page in PHP?

Tags: php, html, post

I know there have a been a lot of questions like this but none (that I have found, and I've looked at many, but correct me if I am wrong) have solved my problem.

As the title of the question suggests, I need to Post select options to another page. My code looks something like this:

```
<form id="join_pool_form" name="join_pool_form"  action="connect.php" method="post"> 

<select name="pool_name" style="width:170px">
<?php
            //The options are from an array. This works fine.
        foreach($poolnames as $value):
            echo '<option value="">'.$value.'</option>';
        endforeach;
        unset($value);
?>
</select>

<input name="passcode" type="password" autofocus required id="passcode" size="35"style="width:170px">

<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Join Pool"> 

</form>
```

The connect.php (action of the form) page has something like this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['pool_name'])) {
    echo "do this";
}else {
    echo "do other";
}
```

So the result of this should be "do this", but I always get "do other". 
I'm very new to this, so excuse me if the solution is extremely simple. However, I have looked over it multiple times to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

---

Thanks everyone for your help. Problem solved.

Comment: You're not setting the `value` attribute on the `<option>` elements. Try something like `'<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>'`.

Comment: ...also you dont need `unset($value);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just have to pass the value in the html attribute of the option:

```
<select name="pool_name" style="width:170px">
<?php
        //The options are from an array. This works fine.
    foreach($poolnames as $value):
        echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
    endforeach;
    unset($value);
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['pool_name'])) {
    $variable =  $_POST['pool_name'];
}else {
    $variable =  'Unknown';
}
```

Comment: Could you please add an explanation to your post on why your solution works?

Answer (score 1):

The value of the select option has to be set to what your intending to send. If you don't set it, it will send nothing.

```
<option value='test'>Dont choose this</option>
```

The above will send the value test.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
echo '<option value="">'.$value.'</option>';
```

with

```
echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short / only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?